# Can someone provide good examples or pointers on how to integrate LDAP with Apex?

Tags: apex

Does anyone have examples or pointers on how to integrate LDAP with Apex? We are running Apache DS and are looking to use our existing LDAP system to manage roles in our customer portal. Before I embark on integrating into the LDAP API from scratch, I thought I would see if anyone else has solved the same req before.

To be clear, this is not about the SSO/SAML capabilities that salesforce has built into the platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only protocol supported from within Salesforce to connect to external services is HTTP(S), so you won't be able to code up LDAP requests from Apex. If your LDAP service also supports an HTTP(S) based API you could call it from Apex, or you could run an integration externally to both systems that talks LDAP to your DS, and uses the Web services APIs to update Salesforce.

Comment: while ldap is an application protocol I imagine one could reverse engineer post and responses pretty quickly. being that ldap responds over HTTPS its just the payload and headers and need to be implemented (unless Im missing something).

Comment: @ebt LDAPS uses TLS for security and has a URN format that looks like a web link it does not use HTTP(S) for data transport. It has it's own protocoll that isn't HTTP compliant and I don't think salesforce would respond to well.

Comment: hmm, your probably right.

Answer (score 2):

[Directory Services Markup Language (DSML)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_Services_Markup_Language) is a representation of directory service information in an XML syntax, typically carried over SOAP/HTTPS. You might want to look at the Fedora [DSML Gateway](http://directory.fedoraproject.org/wiki/DSML) - you should be able to send DSML from Apex to the gateway, and have it translate into LDAP for Apache DS.